# How to use smoldot in rust application?

Tags: rust, javascript, light-client, substrate-connect

I can find only javascript interfaces and documentation to interact with it, but nothing regarding rust?
Feels a bit weird to use js library for rust application in rust application. Neither subxt seems to have possibility of using light client either.

Comment: If you get rust-js-rust working with smoldot then please post a link to your code so we can see it. I find rust to js can be a bit fiddly at times.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [basic example](https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot/blob/main/bin/light-base/examples/basic.rs) you can see how to initialize a Smoldot client. Provide the [chainspec](https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot/blob/76994b52cd658a4ac1dc7a08f6bd4eba702e0e87/bin/light-base/examples/basic.rs#L52) of the chain you want to sync with and make [JSON-RPC requests](https://github.com/paritytech/smoldot/blob/76994b52cd658a4ac1dc7a08f6bd4eba702e0e87/bin/light-base/examples/basic.rs#L79-L104).

But I agree, a native rust interface would be really nice!

Comment: Agreed, but talking with Tomaka he said that there's lots of fun and games that smoldot does to make it work well in the browser and that for now it's a much better idea to do rust to js to smoldot (you will have a lot less pain). For desktop you can use smoldot as a crate - that has worked ok for me: https://github.com/gilescope/polkapipe/blob/main/src/smoldot_std.rs